# Override android package name for Crashlytics reporting

Tags: android, crashlytics, amazon-appstore

In the Amazon AppStore you can distribute both Google Play-style apps and apps heavily customized for the Fire Phone and Fire TV. In order to do this, you generate two different binaries (which can really be quite different and should be thought of as two different apps entirely).

Once the binaries have been created, you need to distribute them to the proper devices via the Amazon AppStore. This is where the problem comes in - since all binaries need to have the same package name.

What is the preferred method to track two different apps which have the same package name using Crashlytics?

I have tried setting a custom package name using the directions found [here](https://gist.github.com/tyvsmith/6188014) for reporting a different package to Crashlytics - however the custom package name never appeared in Crashlytics even after forcing several crashes and observing the SDK upload the reports.

Comment: I think you should have the custom package name have been setted up yet first.

Comment: powerfj, I'm not sure I understand. I can't seem to get the Android Studio plugin to add the app, since it thinks that the app already exists (com.example.android is the package used by all the apps).

Comment: I think becuase you didn't have the package name(like com.example.app_tv) to override install successfully yet in the crashlystics, so you can try to set up a test app with the exactly package name(com.example.app_tv) successfully first, and then override the package in your production app

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the new Fabric's Crashlytics, you can directly configure a package name to use in the Fabric.Builder factory, if not set it defaults to context.getPackageName().

```
Fabric.with(new Fabric.Builder(context).kits(new Crashlytics()).appIdentifier("com.stuff.overriden").build());
```

Comment: This does not work for me. The crashes are still reported using the app's actual package name. Is there anything I need to be aware of?

Comment: I posted a bug report, and since nothing was done we switched to ACRA.
https://twittercommunity.com/t/crashlytics-multiple-packagenames-same-reporting-endpoint-how/53180/2

Comment: I got it to work using this Gist (https://gist.github.com/tyvsmith/6188014) in combination with the solution.

Comment: Can this also work with CrashlyticsCore? When I use the line in this answer, I get an UnmetDependencyException.